# How to perform Firestore validation in functions and send result back to client?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to validate if a username exists in Firestore. I do this in the functions, it looks like this:

```
exports.checkUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  // Uses the username from the data to compare it to the doc
  const usernameExists = await admin
    .firestore()
    .collection('users')
    .doc(data.username)
    .get();

  // Check the the username passed exists
  if (usernameExists.exists) {
    //If the username that is passed exists, we want to repond with an error
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      'already-exists',
      'This username is already taken. Please try another one.'
    );
  }
```

On the client-side, I have something like this:

```
async register({ username, email, password }) {
    const callUsernameFunction = this.functions.httpsCallable('checkUser');
    const usernamePrint = callUsernameFunction({ username });
    return usernamePrint;
  }
```

My Cloud Firestore looks like this:
[image: this is what my cloud firestore looks like]

This works great. When I type in a username that is already being used, I get back an error that says that it is already being used. However, I'm not sure how to implement a `this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);` in this. The behavior should be as follows:

- The user submits the username, email, and password
- Sends an `httpsCallable` to the functions
- Functions checks if the user exists and returns an error if not
- If the user exists, throw the error, if not `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` and log the new user into Cloud Firestore

If it helps I'm using ReactJS with Gatsby for frontend.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the user in the cloud function as shown below,

```
exports.checkUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    // Uses the username from the data to compare it to the doc
    const usernameExists = await admin
        .firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .doc(data.username)
        .get();

    // Check the the username passed exists
    if (usernameExists.exists) {
        //If the username that is passed exists, we want to repond with an error
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
            'already-exists',
            'This username is already taken. Please try another one.'
        );
    } else {
        const newUser = await admin
            .auth()
            .createUser({ email: data.email, password: data.password });

        await admin
            .firestore()
            .collection('users')
            .doc(data.username)
            .set({ userId: newUser.uid });

        return {
            success: true,
            data: data,
        };
    }
});
```

On the client side, log the user on successful user creation.